# Problemas con rutas que tienen el mismo prefijo en laravel ¿Como solucionarlo?

Tags: laravel, rutas

Hola aqui una pregunta rapida llevo horas revisando pero no encuentro como solucionarlo. Tengo estas dos rutas

```
Route::resource('/admin/usuarios', UsersController::class)->names('users');
Route::delete('/admin/usuarios/delete-all', [UsersController::class, 'destroyAll']);
```

Una lo hago con resource y la otra es una ruta personalizada

el problema es que cuando intento hacer una solicitud http con ajax a la ruta personalizada no es capaz de encontrarla sale el tipico error 404. Pero si cambio el prefijo usuarios por users. Algo asi:

```
Route::delete('/admin/users/delete-all', [UsersController::class, 'destroyAll']);
```

si puedo procesar la solicitud. Entonces no entiendo por que este problema acaso ¿cuando se usa resource no se puede crear mas rutas con el mismo prefijo?

```
/admin/usuarios/otro-ruta
admin/usuarios/otra-ruta-2
admin/usuarios/........
```

¿Como podria solucionar eso? o ¿porque se da ese problema?

Comment: Hola, Esto puede suceder cuando tienes una ruta de recurso y una ruta personalizada que comparten el mismo prefijo. Laravel procesa las rutas en el orden en que se registran. Por lo tanto, si tu ruta personalizada se registra después de la ruta del recurso, Laravel puede interpretar el segmento de la ruta personalizada como un parámetro para la ruta del recurso1. Una solución sería cambiar el orden de las rutas en tu archivo de rutas. Deberías registrar tu ruta personalizada antes de la ruta del recurso1 (las dos primeras líneas de código invertidas en el orden)

Comment: de todas las soluciones posibles no se me ocurrio eso. Funciona gracias por tu tiempo y ayudarme a entender el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edito>
Esto puede suceder cuando tienes una ruta de recurso y una ruta personalizada que comparten el mismo prefijo. Laravel procesa las rutas en el orden en que se registran. Por lo tanto, si tu ruta personalizada se registra después de la ruta del recurso, Laravel puede interpretar el segmento de la ruta personalizada como un parámetro para la ruta del recurso1. Una solución sería cambiar el orden de las rutas en tu archivo de rutas.